# Semantic search tools recommandation

Tags: python, framework, text-search

I am looking for a Python Framework that is able to return the sentences that contain a given word/sentence and also to return the ones that contain synonyms of that word.
For example, if I search: "small house" in a text file, the result should be  :

1. the sentences which contains "small house" i.e. "A small house is situated near the lake ..."
2. the sentences which contains synonyms i.e. "And this beautiful tiny house can be rent for only..."

I heard about Solr and Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch is a better version of Solr.The problem is that in order to get synonyms from Elasticsearch you need to manually write each synonym for your query. I am looking for a tool that already does both types of query.